# Auto Complete Textview

Tags: android, android-layout, autocompletetextview, text-formatting

Is there a way to set the format of AutoCompleteTextview like cellphone number with dashes?

I have an AutoCompleteTextview  with custom adapter that suggests account numbers from sqlite table and it shows like this.

[image]

but when i click the suggested account number I want it to look like phone number format and make it like 110-0011. Is that possible for AutoCompleteTextview?

Comment: yes we can do but let us know what you tried and where you stuck?

Comment: is it a static pattern that you want to add '-' after 3 digits? what's the logic behind this?

Comment: actually I want to add '-' after 4 digits and it starts from the right side

Comment: I've tried non so far cuz I don't if it's possible.. But I googled some info about edittext formatting but it doesn't apply here because I'm using AUtoCompleteTextview With Custom Adapter,